# Getter Memoization browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Referencing: [Smart self overwriting lazy getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters)

Does any one know if there are any caveats to being able to depend on the browser memoization for these getters?

By caveat I mean: Do different browsers choose to not memoize these values?

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear. In the example you linked to the getter *overwrites* itself with the value it calculates. What do you mean 'browser memoization'? Also, I would *never* use this sort of thing unless it was very, very clear that it was a bottleneck. Optimization works for today, code clarity forever.

Comment: What do you mean by "*browser memoization*"? Also, are you looking for caveats of the technique itself, or for browser compatibility problems?

Comment: Jared, the part about memoization is in the middle of the paragraph. It actually isn't about performance. It is about how angular js has scope digest issues when you use Object.define property to create a getter that allow functionality upon the getting of a property in an object. Using the object literal get property() syntax does not cause these scope digest explosions due to the value memoization.

Comment: Bergi, I'm looking for if all browsers fully implementing es5 will memoize the values in these getters.

Comment: Yes, of course it does work in all es5-compliant browsers.

Comment: Okay, with all the es6,es5 stuff on mdn, sometimes it is hard to know what parts are es6 and what are es5. I  use babel as a transpiler so I was hoping that the memoization was not a polyfill.

Comment: Can the relevant information be included in the question itself? I have no idea what this is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do different browsers choose to not memoize these values?

No, why would they? This technique works in every ES5-compliant browser, as it only requires getters (and maybe `Object.defineProperty`) - which have nothing to do with ES6, btw.

Comment: I hope no one is confusing memoization using a library like underscore with memoization done in the es5 implementation using getters/setters on POJOs

Comment: Well, imo one shouldn't really call it memoisation anyway. It's just a *lazily* computed property. The only memoisation that happens here is of the getter function (which actually works quite like the underscore implementation).